# Mysql Group by 2 query in 1

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum

I have 2 different queries but uses same date column group. Is there any way to use them in one sql query?

status = 1 means certain
status = 0 means optional

```
1. Query = 'SELECT book_day, sum(pax) as pax, count(*) FROM rezervations WHERE  book_day BETWEEN :first_day AND :end_day AND status = 1 GROUP BY book_day';


2. Query = 'SELECT book_day, sum(pax) as pax, count(*) FROM rezervations WHERE  book_day BETWEEN :first_day AND :end_day AND status = 0 GROUP BY book_day';
```

i would like to have result like

```
    '2020-08-15' | 50 pax status 1(certain) | 20 pax  status 0 (optional)
    '2020-08-18' | 10 pax status 1(certain) | 5 pax  status 0 (optional)

.....
...
..
.
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Case when is answered my question. Here is the query:

```
select 
    book_day, 
    sum(case when status = 1 then pax else 0 end) as certain,
    sum(case when status = 0 then pax else 0 end) as optional
from 
    rezervations 
group by 
    book_day
```

And result is:

```
(`book_day`, `certain`, `optional`)
('2020-07-26', '15',    '0'),
('2020-07-29', '20',    '7'),
('2020-08-15', '15',    '0'),
('2020-08-27', '20',    '28'),
('2020-08-28', '0',     '22');
```